# How to send the xml data thorugh XHR if Allow Origin header is missing in response?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cors

Note :- I actually edit my old question to this, So ignore Answers.

I want to send some xml data, to a website which is for demo purpose its online actually,

So here is the code,

```
<script>

var params = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'"
 "xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'"
 "xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>"
 "<soap:Body>"
  "<TransferBalance xmlns='http://www.altoromutual.com/bank/ws/'>"
   "<transDetails>"
    "<transferDate>2000-01-01</transferDate>"
    "<debitAccount>20</debitAccount>"
    "<creditAccount>21</creditAccount>"
    "<transferAmount>240</transferAmount>"
   "</transDetails>"
  "</TransferBalance>"
 "</soap:Body>"
"</soap:Envelope>";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
    console.log(xhr.responseXML);
  }
}

xhr.open("POST" ,"http://demo.testfire.net/bank/ws.asmx");

xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://www.altoromutual.com/bank/ws/TransferBalance");

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");



xhr.send("params");

</script>
```

Now when I see the network panel my OPTIONS request were gone good, but where is my original request?

When I see the console panel it says that **missing Access controll Allow Origin?** Now how can I do this?

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Have YouTube tried removing the @?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `tmp_name` key as the first parameter in the `move_uploaded_file`

```
$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
```

Just a heads up, since you are writing a file upload module, properly check for mime types.

For php `5.3+` use `finfo()`

```
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
print_r($finfo->buffer(file_get_contents($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']))); //returns the mime type. Example (image/png)
```

At the very top of the script add error reporting.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also remove the `@` next to `$_FILES`. That's an error suppressor.

Also make sure that `filename` actually exists in the `$_FILES` array.  Do a `print_r($_FILES);`to verify that it actually exists

Comment: I did the same, but the result is same "else { }"

Comment: check folder permission issue? and also check the error log.

Comment: Turn on error reporting too.  Also check for error on upload. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Hello! @Akintunde my tmp folder is in the c:\xampp\tmp and my files are stored in the  c:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\ . so i think that  is the problem. But as i am newbie in php i don't know much about how do i solve?

Answer (score 0):

Use this, as PHP stores the file with a temporary name

```
move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $original_path1)
```

Also, make sure to check the folder permission issue (very common) and error_log as well.